# How to dereference Uuid type?

Tags: rust, reference, uuid

I'm using the [Uuid crate](https://docs.rs/uuid/0.8.2/uuid/) to give unique ids to instantiate each new version of a `Node` struct with a unique identifier. Sometimes I'd like to filter these structs using  `.contains()` to check if a struct's `id` is inside some array of `Vec<Uuid>`.

```rust
use uuid::Uuid; 

struct Node {
    id: Uuid,
}

impl Node {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let new_obj = Node {
            id: Uuid::new_v4()
        };
        new_obj
    }
    
    fn id(&self) -> Uuid {
        self.id
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_objs = vec![
        Node::new(), 
        Node::new(), 
        Node::new(), 
        Node::new(), 
    ];
    let some_ids = vec![my_objs[0].id(), my_objs[3].id()];
}

fn filter_objs(all_items: &Vec<Node>, to_get: &Vec<Uuid>){
    for z in to_get {
        let wanted_objs = &all_items.iter().filter(|s| to_get.contains(*s.id()) == true);
    }
}
```

However this gives the error:

```
error[E0614]: type `Uuid` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src/main.rs:32:72
   |
32 |         let wanted_objs = &all_items.iter().filter(|s| to_get.contains(*s.id()) == true);
   |                                                                        ^^^^^^^
```

How can I enable dereferencing for the `Uuid` type to solve this problem?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=94f36a4e9bb91996c721efb1004c5647)

Comment: What is the point of using `== true`? If it is `true`, then it will be `true`. If it isn't, then it will be `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uuid` doesn't implement the `Deref` trait so it can't be dereferenced, nor does it need to be since you're trying to pass it as an argument to a function with expects a reference. If you change `*s.id()` to `&s.id()` the code compiles:

```rust
fn filter_objs(all_items: &Vec<Node>, to_get: &Vec<Uuid>) {
    for z in to_get {
        let wanted_objs = &all_items
            .iter()
            // changed from `*s.id()` to `&s.id()` here
            .filter(|s| to_get.contains(&s.id()) == true);
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d803f2303ae32748ded3c7120c112649)